# Building VTK from source (trunk)

Tags: vtk, point-cloud-library

I am trying to build VTK from sources as it is a dependency to PLC library which I am trying to build.

I use ccmake.. to select all relevant groups to be built (including Group_imaging), and I can build VTK with no particular problems.

Though, I cannot find vtkImageLoader2.h (and many other headers) anywhere in the system.  As these files are required by PCL, this is a problem.

I checked that the original file exists inside the source tree, and it is indeed inside IO/Image.

I can't understand why the file is not being build and deployed to /usr/local/include, I made sure all modules (groups) are ON in ccmake.

Is this file deprecated, or am I missing the way to deploy it?

EDIT: I discovered that the file belongs to module vtkIOImage that is part of the "StandAlone" group.  The StandAlone group is set "ON" when i run ccmake.  Is this a bug in the build scripts of VTK?

Comment: Building vtk6.1 instead of the trunk (6.3) in the same way produces all the built headers to be copied correctly.  I am inclined to think this might be an issue with the current trunk